# Normal that Bitbucket repo has 50% size of the local repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've been moving multiple Git projects onto Bitbucket repositories. I've noticed that the size of my project on Bitbucket is reported around 50% of its size on my disk. So if the project is 500MB on the disk, it has 250-300MB on the Bitbucket repo.

Do the use some kind of compression for the repos or I have to check if something is not properly pushed to Bitbucket?

PS. `git status` does not show any file out of `git`

Comment: Do a `git gc` and see if your repository size changes.

Comment: maybe the target folder (or similar) is not included on git repo itself? check `.gitignore`